# Windows-7 like window management for Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, gnome

Are there any window management addons I can download to let me dock windows like in Windows 7? Specifically, I want pull to top to maximize, and pull to left and right to dock.

Comment: Have you messed around in ccsm?  Specifically, apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-fusion-extra-plugins (after enabling Universe repository).  Then, run ccsm and search for the Snapping Windows plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it myself, but here is a way to do it: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2009/11/aero-snap-ubuntu-linux.html

Comment: This doesn't feel quite the same, but it's close enough and does what I want (left/right dock and easy maximize).

Comment: Old broken link. Page shows UNADULTERATED FAILURE. I almost peed my pants.

Comment: Tested the link. Works on UBUNTU LTS 16.04. Left, right docking works, but not on maximised windows. Had to toggle maximised windows size before left/right docking.

Answer (score 3):

There are too many window management programs to count in linux!  There are a few vids on You tube giving [step-by-step instructions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOAsNyRE7k4&feature=player_embedded#).  There is also a feature in compiz called '[Grid](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3REDYkeIRgU)' which has been around for years and does much the same thing.  You may get what you want with that without mucking about with a bunch of scripts.